# How to allow for zoom in images with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to allow zoom, but most of my code is in kivy and not in the .py document.  I wanted to allow users to zoom in on the image.

```
BoxLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"
    Image:
        source: r"Dekalbprotocols (1)-026.jpg"
        allow_stretch: False
        keep_ratio: True
        size_hint: 1, 1
```

or

```
BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"
        PageLayout:
            border: "100dp"
            Image:
                source: r"Dekalbprotocols (1)-019.jpg"
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ratio: True

                size_hint: 1, 1

            Image:
                source: r"Dekalbprotocols (1)-020.jpg"
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ratio: True

                size_hint: 1, 1
            Image:
                source: r"Dekalbprotocols (1)-021.jpg"
                allow_stretch: False
                keep_ratio: True

                size_hint: 1, 1
```

Comment: Have a look at [Scatter](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Scatter](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html) Widget like following

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter


class ZoomApp(App):
    def build(self):
        scatter = Scatter(do_translation=False,do_rotation=False)
        image = AsyncImage(source='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630629701731-56481a2dd34a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1502&q=80')
        scatter.add_widget(image)
        return scatter


ZoomApp().run()
```

if you want to use mouse the zoom you need right click on the image any where and then left click to zoom